# How to access a package file form laravel controller

Tags: php, laravel, ups

I am using gabrielbull/ups-api in my laravel project

composer.json as follows

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/",
        "Ups\\": "vendor/gabrielbull/ups-api/src"
    },
    "classmap": [
        "database/seeds",
        "database/factories"
    ]
},
```

The controller code as follows :

```
use Ups\Rate;

$rate = new Ups\Rate($accessKey, $userId, $password);
```

but I am getting an error 
Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Ups\Rate' not found

Comment: You use `Ups\Rate` twice. If your use section contains `use Ups\Rate;`, you have to init class without namespace `$rate = new Rate($accessKey, $userId, $password);`, otherwise remove use section and init class with namespace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your controller can't find the Ups\Rate.

You should be able to do:

```
$rate = new Rate($accessKey, $userId, $password);
```

If not: You should be able to debug this quick with the following code.

```
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php'
use Ups\Rate;
new Rate()
echo Rate::class; // output
```

Comment: @FranklinInnocentF If your problem got solved by this please click on the green check mark under the vote so other people know your question is resolved. And no problem!

Answer (score 0):

It's a PHP package, so once you install it via composer, it's already autoloaded. You don't have to mess with the `composer.json` file. After installing run:

```
composer dumpautoload
```